# WIX 3.x: How to select different directories for features in custom dialog

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I'm fairly new to WIX and need some allowing users to select different directories for different features via the custom dialog.

Directory selection works for INSTALLDIR, but not for other directory IDs. Is there a way to get the browse button in the custom dialog to work for other directory IDs? Am I taking an incorrect approach ?

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the standard WiX bootstrapper you can only provide your end users a control to set `INSTALLDIR`. To set different directories you would have to create your own bootstrapper for which WiX has some base classes and example code (both native and managed) you can use to get started.